# what's necessary and what's not? stripping a rom to the bone

Tags: root-access, pokemon-go

I'm experimenting with using am alternate rom (cm13) as a stopgap method to play Pokemon Go between suhide updates. it's not ideal, due to the large downtime involved with backup and restore between roms just for 1 game, but it has 2 major perks:

1. if niantic's algorithms detect that users are identifying some players by the fact that they'll only log in when there's known working bypasses, then this will circumvent that (legitimately)
2. this complies with niantic's wishes to alienate rooted roms.

I've pretty much stripped all common apps, system and user, plus some audio files (ringtone, alarm, etc) and language files.

nano gapps was installed and I removed a chunk of what that added too. and this brings the total rom size down to about 1220mb installed (996 in system) or 627mb total as TWRP backup. that still seems rather large to me for the purpose of being a walking skeleton.

my question is:
what system files, be it libraries, binaries, fonts, etc etc etc can be straight up deleted without breaking cell, Bluetooth, Wi-Fi, Google Play, web browser (any), or any absolutely necessary core functionality? I want to butcher this rom.

Comment: Could use SlimRoms (If its supported) clue is in the name- Tiny OS. Mine is only a few hundred mb.

Comment: @DanBrown but is that installed or as a backup, and with or without gapps lol

Comment: Is there any AOSP (not -based, just plain AOSP) ROM available? Try one if yes. CM has to tie its own framework and features in.